# Full Campaign Information Facebook PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook

**Issue**

Im trying to find a consistent way of using this Facebook SDK, I've gone through the API on their website and I've found many ways of completing the same thing but no single way has a complete solution.

**What i need**

I need to pull all campaigns-> adsets -> ads on an ad account. The problem i have is facebook doesn't seem to allow me to pull the data grouped like that with more options. So for example using 
`$this->fb->get('/act_'.env('AD_ACCOUNT_ID')."/insightslevel=ad&fields=campaign_id,objective");` (Don't know why its formatted like this..), I can pull all ads data along with the adset id and name and also the campaigns id and name, but the problem is i cant pull an adsets budget, or spend or other fields individually.

**Methods Ive Used**

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account/campaigns/

**My question**

Is there a way to read all data from an ad account including things like budget on different levels of the request:

```
[
'campaign' => [
              'id' => 2873462728374,
              'daily_budget' => 100.00,
              'adsets' => [
                           'id' => 19823487161,
                           'status' => ACTIVE,
                           'ads' => ... etc        
                          ]
          ]
]
```

Comment: The Field Expansion / Nested Request syntax should work the same for Marketing API as it does for Graph API, so try your luck with that -  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced#fieldexpansion

Comment: @misorude this is good but i cant get the spends field for ads, i get an error saying it doesn't exist